# How to filter a many-to-many left join using the rightmost table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following tables:

**Machine**

```
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Blender |
| 2  | Slicer  |
| 3  | Masher  |
```

**Part**

```
| id | name            | instock |
+----+-----------------+---------+
| 1  | Blade           | 5       |
| 2  | Rotating engine | 0       |
| 3  | Plug            | 10      |
| 4  | Wire            | 10      |
```

**MachinePart** (many-to-many)

```
| mid | pid |
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 1   |
| 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 3   |
| 1   | 4   |
| 2   | 1   |
| 2   | 3   |
| 2   | 4   |
```

I want a single query to list all machines with parts (outer joined), **as long as the part is in stock**.

I have tried doing the condition in the LEFT JOIN, but then the middle table generates an unwanted record:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, mp.pid, p.name, p.instock
  FROM machine m
  LEFT JOIN machinepart mp ON mp.mid = m.id
  LEFT JOIN part p ON p.id = mp.pid AND instock > 0

| id | name    | pid  | name  | instock |
+----+---------+------+-------+---------+
| 1  | Blender | 1    | Blade | 5       |
| 1  | Blender | 2    | NULL  | NULL    |  -> I don't want this record
| 1  | Blender | 3    | Plug  | 10      |
| 1  | Blender | 4    | Wire  | 10      |
| 2  | Slicer  | 1    | Blade | 5       |
| 2  | Slicer  | 3    | Plug  | 10      |
| 2  | Slicer  | 4    | Wire  | 10      |
| 3  | Masher  | NULL | NULL  | NULL    |  -> But good, I want this record
```

How do I filter `machinepart` based on a field in the related table `part`?

If it matters, I'm using PostgreSQL. (but I assume the solution will be generic)

Comment: Does adding a UNION SELECT break your "single query" requirement?  Are you looking for just one result set, or just one SELECT?

Comment: @geneSummons I'm sure there are ways of doing this with more complex queries, but I felt it was such a trivial problem that I was the one overlooking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an `INNER JOIN` and then a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, mp.pid, p.name, p.instock
FROM machine m INNER JOIN
     machinepart mp
     ON mp.mid = m.id LEFT JOIN
     part p
     ON p.id = mp.pid AND p.instock > 0;
```

EDIT:

This produces the results that you request:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, mp.pid, p.name, p.instock
FROM machine m LEFT JOIN
     machinepart mp
     ON mp.mid = m.id LEFT JOIN
     part p
     ON p.id = mp.pid 
WHERE (p.instock > 0 OR p.instock IS NULL);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=42f30b1400f0e84f6c24dfbfe6c43a18) is a db<>fiddle.

Seems like unusual logic, though.

Comment: No, I specifically want an outer join. This query removes machine ID 3 from the result.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you've put in the fiddle. One possible solution is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b9ce7/13 although it uses a subquery.

Comment: "Seems like unusual logic" It makes sense in the context I'm working on... and it's not machines and parts XD

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE P.INSTOCK IS NOT NULL
```

You can also get all of the "out of stock" parts with `IS NULL` instead

edit: I didn't see you DO want results for machines with no parts (because neither "part is out of stock" nor "part is in stock" make sense for a machine with no parts?)

```
WHERE P.INSTOCK IS NOT NULL
OR MP.PID IS NULL
```

edit2:  <2nd suggestion won't work either>

Comment: This would effectively turn the query into an inner join, not what I need.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I did say "list all machines with parts (outer joined)", not "all machines and parts". Unfortunately, the OR condition would still remove the corner case of a machine that has all parts out of stock. This fiddle shows it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b9ce7/1